# postgresql query does not find result with foreign letters

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to configure PostgreSQL server so it accepts queries starting with foreign letters like `'ÄÜÖÕäüöõ'`.

I know it's in the database but it can't find it with queries.

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE lower(full_aadress) LIKE lower('%õismäe tee%');
```

And what makes it weirder if a foreign letter is in the middle of a sentence it find the result.

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE lower(full_aadress) LIKE lower('%võru%');
```

The database uses `Encoding: UTF-8, Tablespace: pg_default, Collation: C, Character type: C`

Comment: Did you configure your database to use UTF8?

Comment: @bo-oz yes, it is. `Encoding: UTF-8, Tablespace: pg_default, Collation: C,
Character type: C`

Comment: That should just work without any additional configuration. Make sure that `client_encoding` matches the string encoding you use in your queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for some reason it copied it really weirdly, `õismäe tee` how I made search

Comment: Works for me: http://rextester.com/BAFA59164

Comment: @all Fault is in Collation: C, Character type: C. But right now I have no idea how change them